# Google MAPS JS API doesn't load

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a websites, that occupies the Google Maps JS API, but for some reason, the map stays white, but there's no error in the *Google Chrome Console*.

### HTML code:

```
<div id="map-container-5" class="z-depth-1" style="height: 200px"></div>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key"></script>
```

### JS code:

```
function myMap() {
        var mapProp= {
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
          zoom:5,
        };

        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container- 5"),mapProp);
 }
```

I'm not really getting the point, why this is not working, as there's no error.

My kind of template was: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trymap_intro

Comment: don't show your key ..

Comment: @scaisEdge - anybody can see the key anyway doing `viewsource` on his website.. or seeing the outgoing requests..

Comment: thanks, I removed the key and deleted the old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to simply show a map with your coordinates using the googleapi then do as follows. This will show the map with your lat and lng.

CSS:

```
 #map {
    height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
    width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
   }
```

The HTML

```
<div id="map"></div> /* Place on your page
```

And this BEFORE the /body tag with YOUR key

```
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOURKEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

And the JS script which again is places about the /body

```
<script>
function initMap() {
// The location of Uluru
   var uluru = {lat: 51.5087420, lng: -0.120850};
  // The map, centered at Uluru
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 10, center: uluru});
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your style try using a valid *height* and *width*, and be sure the `div` is visible at startup

```
 <div id="map-container-5" class="z-depth-1" style="height: 200px; width:200px;"></div>
```

And try remove the last comma in mapProp

```
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5
};
```

Is not cleat how invoke the function `myMap()`.. so try also using the code directly in

```
<script>
   var mapProp= {
      center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
      zoom:5
    };

    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container- 5"), mapProp);
</script>
```

and check in your javascript  console  .. for error

Answer (score 0):

The API key you used is W3Schools one! API keys are used for Google to ask for money when your map gets lots of views.

You can get your own API key at https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/ but you also need to register your credit card (or a fake one).

Note that you *don't* need an API key if your project is local (not served via HTTP).

(Also you didn't call `myMap`, so be sure to add `myMap()` to the end of your code.)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. You just need to call the `myMap()` function once it is defined. 
Try running the snippet below. (Same as your code with an additional line for calling `myMap()` function.)

```js
function myMap() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
    zoom: 5,
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container-5"), mapProp);
}

myMap();
```

```html
<div id="map-container-5" class="z-depth-1" style="height: 200px"></div>
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC7q_f_aMi9o-hoSl3PYSVHRlN99AU3nBg"></script>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at Object._.cg (js?key=AIzaSyDdbnd8Y-JXh0iNV_wdHKOFDATWn4TZ4ko&callback:84)
    at new gg (js?key=AIzaSyDdbnd8Y-JXh0iNV_wdHKOFDATWn4TZ4ko&callback:85)
    at myMap (googlemaps.js:6)
    at googlemaps.js:8
_.cg @ js?key=AIzaSyDdbnd8Y-JXh0iNV_wdHKOFDATWn4TZ4ko&callback:84
gg @ js?key=AIzaSyDdbnd8Y-JXh0iNV_wdHKOFDATWn4TZ4ko&callback:85
myMap @ googlemaps.js:6
(anonymous) @ googlemaps.js:8

Answer (score 0):

first you have to get your own key for google maps api. then you need to correct the tag like this.Also you have to call your "**myMap**" function.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=myMap" async defer></script>
```

you then want to replace "YOUR_API_KEY" in the code with your key.
and "myMap" with your function name which in this case is the same (myMap)